# Equivalent of get_or_create for adding users

Tags: django

Is there a simpler way to add a user than with the following pattern?

```
    try:
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    except IntegrityError:
        messages.info(request, "This user already exists.")
    else:
        new_user.first_name = first_name
        # continue with other things
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. But you can proxify the Django User:

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def get_or_create(self, username, email, password, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        except IntegrityError:
            return User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)
        else:
            new_user.first_name = kwargs['first_name'] # or what you want
            ...etc...

        return new_user
```

Comment: It does now, see @nu everest's answer.

Comment: FWIW catching IntegrityError seems weird, weird, weird here. Like the design is backwards. It's *get_or_create* so try to get, catch User.DoesNotExist, then try to create!

Answer (score 23):

In Django 1.4, get_or_create() exists for User.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

_user = User.objects.get_or_create(
        username=u'bob',
        password=u'bobspassword',
    )
```

Comment: In this example, `_user` will be a tuple `(user_object, was_just_created)`.

Comment: This is not going to correctly set the password for the user. The raw `password` field holds the salted hash, not the password itself. You would have to call `set_password()` on the user when newly created, and then save it (again). Not ideal. By the way, you probably wanted to have it in the `defaults` kwarg anyway.

Answer (score 14):

It is better not to catch `IntegrityError` as it can happen for other reasons. You need to check if user exists, excluding the password. If user already exists, set the password.

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, email=email)
if created:
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
```

Comment: I think this needs `user.save()` after `user.set_password()`, otherwise the password will not saved.

Comment: created is true when the record is created so *if* statement should be flipped.

Answer (score 1):

This method should solve this problem but keep in mind that in the database, password is kept as a hash of the password, and as pointed before, "get_or_create" makes an exact lookup. So before the lookup actually happens, we "pop" the password from the kwargs.
This method on your custom UserManager:

```
def get_or_create(self, defaults=None, **kwargs):
    password = kwargs.pop('password', None)
    obj, created = super(UserManager, self).get_or_create(defaults, **kwargs)
    if created and password:
        obj.set_password(password)
        obj.save()
    return obj, created
```

Comment: While this might answer the question it always helps to add some comments or explanation why your code solves the problem.

Comment: Best not to override the base user class for no reason. Just define this function elsewhere.