# Django only login for shell created users

Tags: python, django

I let a user sign up due to the following code:

```
def sign_up(request):

    if request.POST:
        userName = request.POST.get('username')
        passWord = request.POST.get('password')
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=userName, password=passWord)
        user.save() 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:login'))
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response('account/sign_up.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{% extends "base_login.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
```

```
<div id="sign_up"> {% block extension1 %} 
    <form action="/account/sign_up/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }} <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </form> {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The user gets created. I can see this in the database. However, following this way, this newly created user wouldn't be albe to login. Though, users created the same way in shell will be able to login. I tried a lot and found:

```
users_able.password
'pbkdf2_sha256$12000$CczM6MmFkTrj$qA1QG7O4nBSSOh6...'

users_unable.password
'!KAXKN25DPijEmzj0TcrhpHYpyB1pLhue...'
```

So I suppose it has something to do with the password not set properly. Right? I use the default UserCreationForm for signing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the `UserCreationForm`?

Comment: wouldn't know how, it is django built-in

Comment: You can remove user.save() - It's redundant. create_user, creates and saves the user. Also, is there a reason you're using render_to_response, instead of render? What version of Django are you on?

Comment: are you sure you are not creating the user multiple times. See this thread [equivalent-of-get-or-create-for-adding-users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511391/equivalent-of-get-or-create-for-adding-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [How to use django UserCreationForm correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13901319/3096768):

> You can directly save the UserCreationForm which will give you user object.

Allowing you to do something like this:

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:login'))
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am falling around with Django for only one week and sometimes you just get confused with all the possibilities buzzing around. I am trying

Answer (score 0):

Django's UserCreationForm doesn't have a field named password. It has a named password1 and has a password2 field that when enetered should match password1. If you change request.POST.get('password') to request.POST.get('password1') I'm sure this would work. However, I would recommend you not use your method as it's built. You should be seeing if the form is valid before creating a user.